# Why Strcpy function is not working with Pointer to Array?

Tags: c, arrays, string, pointers, strcpy

I am learning about Pointers. This piece of code is producing run time error.
I am trying to insert string in char array using Pointer to char.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
int main()
{
    char *a[10];
    strcpy(*a,"foo");
}
```

Comment: Where is the code to allocate memory for your pointer `a`?

Comment: Doesn't your compile scream while compiling that code? You should listen to it.

Answer (score 2):

You have declared `a` as an array of 10 pointers to `char`.
I think you meant to declare an array of 10 char.

```
char a[10];
```

Changing the declaration would also mean you need to change the call to `strcpy`:

```
strcpy(a,"foo");
```

The program now looks like this:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
int main()
{
    char a[10];
    strcpy(a,"foo");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> Why Strcpy function is not working with Pointer to Array?

This declaration

```
char *a[10];
```

does not declare a pointer to an array. It is a declaration of an array of 10 pointers to objects of type char.

Moreover this array is not initialized and its elements have indeterminate values.

To declare a pointer to an array of the type `char[10]` you should write

```
char ( *a )[10];
```

And the pointer must be initialized by an address of an appropriate array if you are going to use it in the function `strcpy`.

It seems what you mean is the following.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) 
{
    char s[10];
    char ( *a )[10] = &s;

    strcpy( *a, "foo" );

    puts( s );

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
foo
```

In this program there is indeed declared a pointer to a character array of the type `char[10]`

```
    char ( *a )[10] = &s;
```

and the pointer is initialized by the address of the array `s`.

And the dereferenced pointer is used in the function `strcpy`

```
    strcpy( *a, "foo" );
```

Answer (score 1):

char *a[10] is as array of pointers to char, you want char a[10] which is an array of chars